# ETW EventSource for C# not publishing RelatedActivityId GUID to Listener

Tags: c#, event-handling, etw

Writing an Event with the following function:

`WriteEventWithRelatedActivityId(1, MyRelatedActivityGuid, SomeMessage);`

should reasonably pass `MyRelatedActivityGuid` to the Listeners `EventWrittenEventArgs.RelatedActivityId` property.
However, when I consume the event, that property is not set, i.e. its an empty Guid.

What is the issue here? I haven't found any docs that says anything about additional setup for getting it to work.

Regards

Comment: how do you consume it? Have you activated Tpl activity tracking?

Comment: any update on the question?

Comment: Tried activating TAT. Couldn't get it to work. We decided to implement it ourselves in another way.

Comment: ok, post as an answer **how** you solved it.